# TcxGridBand adding a column

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have a TcxGridBandedTableView called cxOptimumView. I am trying to add dynamical. I have created the column as below

```
AColumn := cxOptimumView.CreateColumn;
AColumn.Caption := 'Combo';
AColumn.PropertiesClass := TcxComboBoxProperties;
TcxComboBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).Items.Add('Item1');
TcxComboBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).Items.Add('Item2');
TcxComboBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).Items.Add('Item3');
```

add a column to it? I am trying to do this in delphi. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the new column inside a band.

The following code creates a new band, creates a new column and then places the column into the band (You can use an existing band instead of creating a new one):

```
var
  AColumn : TcxGridBandedColumn;
  ABand : TcxGridBand;
begin
  cxOptimumView.BeginUpdate();
  try
    //adding band
    ABand := cxOptimumView.Bands.Add;
    //adding column
    AColumn := cxOptimumView.CreateColumn;
    AColumn.Caption := 'Combo';
    AColumn.PropertiesClass := TcxComboBoxProperties;
    TcxComboBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).Items.Add('Item1');
    TcxComboBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).Items.Add('Item2');
    TcxComboBoxProperties(AColumn.Properties).Items.Add('Item3');
    //adding column to the band
    AColumn.Position.BandIndex := ABand.Index;
  finally
    cxOptimumView.EndUpdate();
  end;
```

Comment: @Fly: There's a grey check icon on the left of the answer's text, you can click on it for accepting the answer. Click [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a more detailed explanation.